# visualforce create dropdown from custom list

Tags: apex, visualforce, force.com

I have created a custom list using inner classes, this list is called "openPresentations". This list looks like this when I do json.serialize

[{"name": "First Name","id": "a09N0000002R0oeIAC"},

{"name": "Second Name","id": "a09N0000002R0p4IAC"},

{"name": "Third Name","id": "a09N0000002R0dpIAC"},

{"name": "Fourth Name","id": "a09N0000003LxoEIAS"}]

I am trying to add this list into a dropdown in a VF page, with the main purpose of displaying the name in the dropdown and when it is submitted I want to grab the id.

I have unsuccessfully tried something like:

`<apex:selectList size="1"> 
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!openPresentations}" /> 
 </apex:selectList>`

but i am keep getting and error
"Invalid selectOptions found. Use SelectOption type in Apex. "
and if I change to SelectOption i get exactly the same error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to populate a `List<SelectOption>` to bind with the UI. Also have a variable to grab which have been selected from the select options. In your controller have below codes

```
public String selectedVal{get;set;}  // This will hold the selected value, the id in here

public List<SelectOption> getopenPresentationOptions(){
        List<SelectOption> optns = new List<Selectoption>();
        // before getting here you must populate your queryResult list with required fields
        for(Your_Object obj : queryResult){
           optns.add(new selectOption(obj.Id, obj.Name));
        }            

        return optns;
}
```

VF Page:

```
<apex:selectList value="{!selectedVal}" size="1"> 
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!openPresentationOptions}" /> 
</apex:selectList>
```

**UPDATE** : added code so that selectoptions list will be populated with a query result

Comment: because the list "openPresentations" is a result of a query of two different object (that is why i used an inner class), so i cant hard code the options value, is it possible to loop through "openPresentations" ?

Comment: Yes. Add records into the `optns` list inside a loop so that you can populate it with the query results. See my update

Comment: Sorry still not very clear, I cant understand your comment of  "before getting here you must populate your queryResult list with required fields" do you meant that in this section should go the code where I create my list openPresentations? so query result = openPresentations ?

Comment: forget that comment and just try out the code. If you can edit your question and add your controller code where you querying these people can help you.

Comment: Thank you highfive, I understand now, I though that i needed to create a list using inner classes, but I tested and seems to work fine if i just type the query there

Answer (score 3):

To bind your options from Apex to your visualforce using apex:selectOptions you need to use the SelectOption object type in Apex.

Your getOpenPresentations method should look something like this:

```
 public List<SelectOption> getOpenPresentations() {
    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
    options.add(new SelectOption('a09N0000002R0oeIAC','Firstname'));
    options.add(new SelectOption('a09N0000002R0p4IAC','Second Name'));
    return options;
}
```

More information can be found here: https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/apex_pages_selectoption.htm

Comment: Thank you so much if I copy this i get an error Unknown property. Also this is hard coded as I said at the beginning this string is the result of a query (that is why i am using inner class)

Comment: Small Typo, I assume it should be getOpenPresentations.

Comment: Cool! glad to help you :)